# Facebook Page Account: but the application does not register?

Tags: facebook, account

I "Created a Page" on the Facebook website, created an account.
Then, developer registration authentication of the developers page .
But when I try to register the mobile application,it will continue to fail.

When I click "https://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php" , I go to the my 
Facebook Page Account: but why the application does not register?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a personal Facebook account to create applications. You can not use "page accounts".

This is so that Facebook will be able to track "bad" applications back to a real (verified) user.